# How to randomly split data into three equal sizes?

Tags: r, random, group-by, dplyr, divide

I have a dataset with 9558 rows from three different projects. I want to randomly split this dataset in three equal groups and assign a unique ID for each group, so that `Project1_Project_2_Project3` becomes `Project1`, `Project2` and `Project3`.

I have tried many things, and googled codes from people with similar problem as I have. I have used `sample_n()` and `sample_frac()`, but unfortunately I can't solve this issue myself :/

I have made an example of my dataset looking like this:

```
ProjectName <- c("Project1_Project2_Project3")
data <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,9558,rep=TRUE)))
data <- data.frame(ProjectName, data)
```

And the output should be randomly split in three equal group of `nrow=3186` and then assigned to the values

```
ProjectName Count of rows
Project1     3186
Project2     3186
Project3     3186
```

Comment: when you say split this means that you do not want repeats in the groups right? as in data in 15 is only in 1 set

Comment: Does `c("Project1", "Project2", "Project3")` instead of `c("Project1_Project2_Project3")` give you what you want?

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf Yes, i dont want repeats in the groups. What do you mean in 15 is only 1 set?

Comment: @jay.sf The real dataset that I have contains data from three different projects and there is only one unique ID for this and it is structured the same way as the one I made. But I would like to split it randomly into three equal groups and each group should have their own name: Project1, Project2 and Project3 :)

Comment: This question needs to be simply modified and asked in a better way to be useful for others too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO it should be sufficient to assign just random project names.

```
dat$ProjectName <- sample(factor(rep(1:3, length.out=nrow(dat)), 
                          labels=paste0("Project", 1:3)))
```

***Result***

```
head(dat)
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 ProjectName
# 1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1   0    Project1
# 2  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   0    Project1
# 3  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   1    Project1
# 4  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0   1    Project3
# 5  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   1    Project1
# 6  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1   1    Project3

table(dat$ProjectName)
# Project1 Project2 Project3 
#     3186     3186     3186
```

***Data***

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(0:1, 9558, rep=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem once.  This is how I did it.  If you just use sample, the groups are uneven, by sampling off a vector where the groups are even worked for me.

```
sampleframe <- rep(1:3, ceiling( nrow( data)/3 ) ) 

data$grp <- 0
data[  , "grp"  ] <- sample( sampleframe , size=nrow( data) ,  replace=FALSE )

project1 <- data[data$grp %in% 1 ,]
project2 <- data[data$grp %in% 2 ,]
project3 <- data[data$grp %in% 3 ,]
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the solution [in this comment](https://gist.github.com/dsparks/3695362#gistcomment-1585309) to a Github gist.

You could generate the indices as suggested:

```
folds <- split(sample(nrow(data), nrow(data), replace = FALSE), as.factor(1:3))
```

Then get a list of 3 equal size data frames using:

```
datalist <- lapply(folds, function(x) data[x, ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an `id` to `data`:

```
data$id <- 1:nrow(data)
```

Take the first sample:

```
project1 <- dplyr::sample_frac(data, 0.33333)
```

Remove the used rows from data and save into `project2`:

```
project2 <- data[!(data$id %in% project1$id), ]
```

Sample half of the remainder:

```
project3 <- dplyr::sample_frac(project2, 0.5)
```

Finally remove those in the `project3` sample from `project2`:

```
project2 <- project2[!(project2$id %in% project3$id), ]
```

Check all `id`s are unique:

```
# should all be FALSE
any(project1$id %in% project2$id)
any(project1$id %in% project3$id)
any(project2$id %in% project3$id)
```

And double-check the data frames have the right number of cases:

```
nrow(project1)
nrow(project2)
nrow(project3)
```